# Запись значения в firebase realtime database построчно

Tags: android, json, firebase

В cardView нужно вывести четверостишье. 
[![cardView][1]][1] Пробовала записывать в database перевод на новую строку так -  Когда теряет равновесие"\n"
твоё сознание усталое,"\n"
когда ступеньки этой лестницы"\n"
уходят из под ног...

и с одинарными кавычками '\n' и без ковычек \n, c двойным слешем \n. Все варианты по советам из интернета перепробовала. Все равно выводится как на скриншоте.

p.s. Стихотворение должно быть под одним ключом.

Ну и xml код cardView

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="15dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_poem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Считываю данные:

```
 private void updateList() {
    reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            result.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(ModelPoem.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ModelPoem modelPoem = dataSnapshot.getValue(ModelPoem.class);
            int index = getPoemIndex(modelPoem);
            result.set(index, modelPoem);
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);

        }
```

где result это список объектов ModelPoem `List<ModelPoem> result;`

```
public class ModelPoem {
    public String title;
    public String poem;
    public int key;
```

Comment: Без кавычек. Как храните json на сервере? И как читаете?

Comment: json должен быть такого вида :  "title": "перенос \n текста",

Comment: обновила вопрос

Comment: должна быть строка "Когда теряет равновесие \n твоё сознание устало" безо всяких кавычек. Если у вас recyclerView, то данные вроде как добавляются в адаптер в методе onChildAdded. Если делать методом .replace("_n","/n"); это может вызывать тормоза. Если в списке делать через replace, то тогда в геттере возращать значение через .replace("_n","/n"); Я думаю это не лучший выход. Скорее не корректно составлен json или считывается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

Отправляйте в database вместо `\n` , к примеру `_n`.

При получении заменяйте `_n` на `\n`

```
(String) dataSnapshot.child("content").getValue().replace("_n","/n");
```